# Print half left pyramid/triangle and half right pyramid/triangle together

Tags: c

Newb Here!

Trying some things with C Language,
I tried to print Half left triangle/pyramid and Half right triangle/pyramid together in one print.

heres the code!

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <conio.h>
int main()  
{  
    int i, j, rows, k;  
    printf (" Enter a number to define the rows: \n ");  
scanf("%d", &rows);  
printf("\n");  
for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) // outer loop  
{  
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) // inner loop  
    {  
        printf ("*"); // print the Star  
    }  
    printf ("\n");   
}  
{ 
for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)   
{  
    for (j = i; j < rows; j++)  
    {  
        printf(" ");   
    }  
    for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)  
    {  
        printf("*"); // print the Star  
    }  
    printf ("\n");   
  }  
 }  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Add more details on how the pyramid should look.

Comment: uh, they should be printed side to side like a pyramid/triangle but the center is vertical hollow(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <conio.h>
int main()  
{  
    int i, j, rows, k;
    int hollow_spacing = 2;
    int left_padding = 10;
    printf (" Enter a number to define the rows: \n ");  
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("\n");  
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        int curr_left_pad = left_padding + rows - i;
        while(curr_left_pad-- > 0){
            printf (" ");
        }

        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            printf ("*");
        for (int j = 0; j < hollow_spacing; ++j)
            printf (" ");
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            printf ("*");
        
        printf ("\n");   
    }
}
```

[image]